# Translating media and other reference fields

Tags: 10

I am new to Drupal and I am setting up a new Drupal 10 website with multiple languages. I just wanna make sure that as a beginner I have understood the concept of translation for fields that reference to other entities.

For example, I have an *Article* content type with three fields:

- field_related_pages that references multiple *Page* nodes
- field_main_image that references a media entity (an Image bundle)
- field_related_places which references a *Places* vocabulary

From what I've concluded from my search, those three fields should be marked as NON Translatable on the *Article* content type. Moreover, on the configuration page admin/config/regional/content-language, the *Places* vocabulary should be marked as translatable with all its translatable fields, the content type page should be also marked as translatable with all its translatable fields, the Image should also be marked as translatable with all its translatable fields.

Is this correct, or should I mark the field_main_image field  as translatable from the beginning in the *Article* content type?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer: Yes, this is correct.

Only make reference fields translatable when they should have completely different values in different languages.

Comment: Thank You for your clear answer!